# what's the difference between the following queries. which is the most effective way to execute?

Tags: mysql

A.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `photo` 
      INNER JOIN `photo_comment` 
          ON `photo`.id = `photo_comment`.photo_id 
LIMIT 0,2
```

B.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `photo_comment`) AS T,`photo` 
WHERE T.photo_id = `photo`.id 
LIMIT 0,2
```

C.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `photo_comment`,`photo` 
WHERE `photo`.id=`photo_comment`.photo_id 
LIMIT 0,2
```

what's the difference between the following queries. which is the most effective way to execute?

Thanks in advance for any help and enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query and the third query are the same. The first query uses `ANSI SQL-92` format while the third query (*the old one*) uses `SQL-89` format.

The second query is slower (*but not totally slower*) because it scans the the `photo_comment`  first and joins it with the other table.

Comment: It might, but that depends on the version of MySQL you are running.

Answer (score 0):

First and third queries are similar. Second is the slowest one because of using temporary table to store result of inner select.